# Access - Filter by date with a checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to have a check-box that, when ticked, filters the loaded data to only include data where it has been at least one month until the "Expected pair maturation" date. Here is my attempt:

```vb
Private Sub LockFilter1Chk_Click()

If Me!LockFilter1Chk = True Then
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM staff " & _
WHERE DateDiff("m", Me![Expected pair maturation], Now()) > 1 "
End If

If Me!LockFilter1Chk = Not True Then
Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Staff "
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be simple to set the Filter:

```
Private Sub LockFilter1Chk_Click()

    If Me!LockFilter1Chk = True Then
        Me.Filter = "[Expected pair maturation] < DateAdd("m", -1, Date())"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.FilterOn = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works, however it does not filter out results based on whether the difference in dates is one month. I have already used this kind of filter in my query.

Answer (score 1):

After a string and line concatenation `& _` you need a new double quote to start the new string.

If you have `"` inside a string, you must mask it as `""`.

In a SQL SELECT recordsource, don't refer to `Me!`. You are comparing the value from the table, so only use the field name.

Some indentation helps a lot with readability.

This should be closer (not sure if it already does what you want).

```vb
Private Sub LockFilter1Chk_Click()

If Me!LockFilter1Chk = True Then
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM staff " & _
      "WHERE DateDiff(""m"", [Expected pair maturation], Now()) > 1 "

Else
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM Staff "
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the problem with my syntax, and providing formatting advice.

Comment: Currently, with ""m"" > 1, the dates have to be e.g. "dd/01/yyyy" to get through the filter if the date were "dd/03/yyyy"
I'm going to change ""m"" to ""d"", and the limit to be >28 (4 weeks). I might also try ""m"" > 0, depending on whether ""d"" accounts for changes in months.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention what was your problem.
You can do it the way you did, but I would use an if then else construct:

```
Private Sub LockFilter1Chk_Click()
    If Me!LockFilter1Chk = True Then
       Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM staff " & _ 
                         "WHERE [Expected pair maturation] < DateAdd('m', -1, Date())"
    else
       Me.RecordSource = "Staff"
    End If
End Sub
```

Alternatively you could leave the record Source unchanged and use a filter:

```
If Me!LockFilter1Chk = True Then
   docmd.applyfilter , "[Expected pair maturation] < DateAdd('m', -1, Date())"
else
   me.filterOn = false
end if
```

Note: If you have quotes within quotes, you can also use *single* quotes *inside*:

```
"DateDiff('m', Me![Expected pair maturation], Now()) > 1 "
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution that sticks with the RecordSource method, the filter method, and the syntax advice. In the RecordSource method, how does the code know it's looking for a difference in months - is this the default behaviour?

Comment: As I said to Gustav, the solution is nice, but without a ">1 month" part the filter doesn't work as desired. The DateDiff syntax you mentioned should work with Andre's answer, though.

Comment: @Idios: you're right, I corrected my answer. I had missed the "month" part, I thought you where looking for the day before.